# Can I lose the upload button of PrimeReact FileUpload component and assign the behavior of the upload button to a different submit button?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, primereact

```
import { FileUpload } from 'primereact/fileupload';
import { Button } from "primereact/button";
import React from 'react';

 const InfoChangeRequest = () => {
 const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card">
   
                 <div className="mt-4">
                 <FileUpload name="demo[]" url={"../../public/images/"} multiple accept="image/*" maxFileSize={1000000}
                        emptyTemplate={<p className="m-0">{t("fileUploadDefaultText")}</p>}
                        chooseLabel={t("choose")}
                        cancelLabel={t("cancel")}
                        uploadLabel={t("upload")}
                        customUpload={true}
                        onUpload={ e => console.log( e )}
                        uploadHandler={ e => console.log ( e ) }
                        onSelect={onTemplateAdvancedSelect}

                />
                </div>

               <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-content-center mt-5">
                  <Button label={t("submit")} icon="pi pi-check" className=" p-3"/>
               </div>

     </div>

   </>
)
}
export default withTranslation()(InfoChangeRequest);
```

I want to send the uploaded file and other stuff under the submit button. Therefore, I need to remove the upload button, which is the first step.